neighboring tones vs passing tones
My question is quite simple: I'm not quite clear on the difference between neighboring tones and passing tones. I haven't found any really helpful sites online that explain this, either.
If someone could explain to me how to determine if a note in a given passage is a neighboring tone or a passing tone in simple terms, that would be great! :)
(P.S. I am currently learning a Melody Writing unit in my music theory book, if that is helpful in any way.)

A passing tone sits between two different chord tones. For example, given C major and a passage C-D-E, the D is a passing tone.
A neighbor tone returns a pitch to itself. C-D-C and E-D-E both include D as a neighbor tone.

A neighbor note doesn't have to return to itself.  I can be used to create and release tension, for example A-F#-G (in the key of G)

@Duston, depending on how you classify NCTs, you're describing changing tones.

Non-chord tones are named/classified by the motion of approach to the dissonant tone and the motion of resolution.
Another model you will see frequently, in relation to a "suspension", is preparation dissonance resolution.
Two web sites using these criteria...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonchord_tone
https://tobyrush.com/theorypages/pdf/en-us/non-harmonic-tones.pdf

Passing tones approach a dissonant tone by step and resolve to a chord tone by step in the same direction, ex. C5 D5 E5 over chords C G C.
Neighbor tones approach a dissonant tone by step and resolve by step returning to the previous tone, ex. C5 B4 C5 over chords C G7 C.
In my two examples, imagining the key is C major, the tones are all diatonic and harmonically they depart from and return to the same chord, the C major chord. While that kind of thing will be common it is not necessarily part of the definition for NCTs. You could have something like E4 D#4 E4 over chords C (C) Am, where the neighboring motion is chromatic, not diatonic, and the "preparation" chord is C major while the "resolution" chord is a new chord A minor.
The specific chords do not matter for the naming on non-chord tones, nor whether they involve diatonic or chromatic tones. Sometimes you see distinctions of whether the dissonant tone is metrically accented, but that is just a modifying detail. For example, a metrically accented passing tone.
Also, you don't need to try figuring out the "chord" of the dissonant tone. The whole point is you will have one or more dissonant tones that will not combine to a normal chord. For example, in my case of E4 D#4 E4 over chords C (C) Am, I put the second chord, the one with the dissonance, in parenthesis to show it really does not need to be identified. It's really just a prolonging of the C chord. Enharmonically the D# might sound like Eb and the chord could be heard like Cm, but it is not necessary to find a chord identity at that point. At that moment the active harmonic elements are dissonance and a lack of a clear chord.

Adding to Aaron's answer, a passing tone is a note which 'joins' between two notes (stepwise) in the same direction. Generally between two diatonic notes,an interval of a step is equal to that of a tone, or two semitones.
